# Where to place require and use statements in a php class

Tags: php

I'm new to php and a program I'm creating is not working as expected. I'm struggling to find the error, so I want to make sure that I'm placing the require and use statement in the correct position. In the code sample below, are the require and use statement in the correct position? Or should it be within the class definition?

```
<?php

require 'abc.php'; 

use xyz;

class foo
{
  //or should I place both of them here?

  function bar ()

  {

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Who not take a look at some real world code? https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Logger.php

Comment: Thanks Ale, but I don't see a 'require' statement there. Can I assume it is in the same place as the 'use' statement?

Comment: I suppose yes, that's how the [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually best practice is to have them **outside** of class. `Require` statements are loaded with auto-loading and `namespaces` and `use`-s are outside.

For example check out this modern framework: [Nette: Compiler class](https://github.com/nette/nette/blob/master/Nette/DI/Compiler.php). Browse it on github and you will see what I am talking about. Loader looks like this: [Nette: Loader](https://github.com/nette/nette/blob/master/Nette/loader.php).

Comment: Why do you think so? :)

Comment: I just opened [Nette: Compiler class.](https://github.com/nette/nette/blob/master/Nette/DI/Compiler.php) and I notice `static` methods, tight coupling of the `Validators`,  `Config\Helpers` and `Statement` (and other) classes. High cyclomatic and npath complexity. And that's just one file I looked at.